# How to get reports names from Get-PowerBIReport

Tags: powershell, powerbi-desktop

I need to get every workspace and every report I have connected to a specific user (It's a virtual user to have an overview and control of reports in my organization). I am trying to do this via powershell. Everything works fine except report names.

When i run this code:

```
$Workspaces =
ForEach ($Workspace in (Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All -Include All ))
{
[pscustomobject]@{
WorkspaceID = $Workspace.Id
WorkspaceName = $Workspace.Name
#User = $Workspace.Users -join '?'
ReportName = $Workspace.Reports -join ','

}
}
```

In the ReportName column i have:
*Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.Report,Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.Report*

When i add toString() to $Workspace.Reports:

```
$Workspaces =
ForEach ($Workspace in (Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All -Include All ))
{
[pscustomobject]@{
WorkspaceID = $Workspace.Id
WorkspaceName = $Workspace.Name
#User = $Workspace.Users -join '?'
ReportName = $Workspace.Reports.ToString() -join ','

}
}
$Workspaces | Export-Csv -Path $logpath -NoTypeInformation
```

In the ReportName column I have: *System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.Report*

The goal is to have WorkspaceId, WorkspaceName, Users and Report Names. Is there any way to do this? I tired a lot of ways i found on the internet but this is the first time I use powershell so nothing worked. Thank You in advance.

Comment: What do you get with `ReportName = $Workspace.Reports.Name -join ', '` ?

Comment: Im very sorry for late answear.
I didn't get any report name
WorkspaceID nad WorkspaceName is fine, but It didn't return any report names

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in this solution, this would keep you covered as much Get-PowerBIReport can provide

```
<#
Install these libraries first if you want to use below cmdlets
$PSVersionTable
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Force
#>

#Log in to Power BI Service 2 options Login or connect
Login-PowerBI  -Environment Public 
#Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential (Get-Credential)

#First, Collect all (or one) of the workspaces in a parameter called PBIWorkspace
$PBIWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace    # Collect all workspaces you have access to
#$PBIWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name 'workspace name'    #Use the -Name parameter to limit to one workspace

#Now collect todays date
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd" 

#Almost finished: Build the outputpath. This Outputpath creates a news map, based on todays date
$OutPutPath = "C:\report\" + $TodaysDate 

#Now loop through the workspaces, hence the ForEach
ForEach($Workspace in $PBIWorkspace)
{
    #For all workspaces there is a new Folder destination: Outputpath + Workspacename
    $Folder = $OutPutPath + "\" + $Workspace.name 
    #If the folder doens't exists, it will be created.
    If(!(Test-Path $Folder))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder
    }
    #At this point, there is a folder structure with a folder for all your workspaces 
    
    
    #Collect all (or one) of the reports from one or all workspaces 
    $PBIReports = Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $Workspace.Id   # Collect all reports from the workspace we selected.
    
       # (optional enable to use) Only Selecting particular reports for selective download
       #$SelectedReportList = $PBIReports.name | select-string -pattern ('some pattern') # '_UAT$', ending with _UAT reports only.

       #creating array variable to append all names and details together
       $Reports_list = @() 

       #foreach loop to append all details in a csv file
       ForEach($Report in $PBIReports.name)
     {
       $Reports_list += Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $Workspace.Id -Name $Report
     }
       $OutputFile = $OutPutPath + "\"+$Workspace.name +"\" + "Report_list.csv"
       $Reports_list | Export-csv $OutputFile

}
```